# If $\frac{a}{\sin{A}}=\frac{b}{\cos{A}}$, show that $\sin{A}\cos{A}=\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I don't know how to go about solving this, I think I need to use $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

The closest I managed to get was:

$$\frac{a}{\sin{A}}=\frac{b}{\cos{A}}$$
$$a\cos{A}-b\sin{A}=0$$
$$a^2\cos^2{A}+b^2\sin^2{A}-2ab\cos{A}\sin{A}=0$$
$$\cos{A}\sin{A}=\frac{a^2\cos^2{A}+b^2\sin^2{A}}{2ab}$$

Which seems to vaguely resemble what I need, but I'm not sure of the final steps.

Comment: You can note that $a = b\tan A$. Try and substitute this into the right-hand side of the equality you need to prove, and make use of trigonometric identities.

Comment: This is a *show that* question. Using the intended result when answering the question is almost always disallowed in these questions.

Comment: @RhysHughes Sorry, I disagree. If the problem says express $\sin\, A \cos \, A$ intrems of $a$ and $b$ we cannot start with $\frac {ab} {a^{2}+b{2}}$ (coming from nowhere). When it says 'show that' we can start from either RHS or LHS.

Comment: Would it be OK if the question was "show that $\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}=\sin A \cos A$" instead? If not, why not? If so, then the original problem is logically equivalent to this, so it should be fine.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy the idea of these questions (in exams/textbooks, which is definitely where this came from) is and always will be to manipulate the LHS to get the RHS. Instead, you should use the end result as a checker to see if your workings are correct. THAT is the reason they give you the desired form in the question, in addition there may be some other convoluted expression for $\sin A \cos A$ that the examiner doesn't expect if your question were put through. I agree, you CAN start from LHS or RHS, just don't expect  to get any marks doing the latter.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth No, it wouldn't, because you are still using a result which hasn't been verified, and that is considered bad practice

Comment: Would the proof be considered invalid then (going from RHS to LHS in the original question)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that
$$ \sin A \cos A = \frac{\sin A \cos A}{\sin^2 A + \cos^2 A} = \frac{\tan A}{\tan^2 A + 1} $$
It should be ease for you to continue.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you have $$\frac{a}{\sin{A}}=\frac{b}{\cos{A}}$$ which is equivalent to $$ \tan A = \frac {a}{b}$$

Now $$\sin A \cos A = (1/2) \sin (2A) = \frac {\tan A}{1+ \tan^2 A} = \frac {ab}{a^2 + b^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: just substitute $a=b\frac {\sin \, A}{\cos \, A}$ in $\frac {ab} {a^{2}+b^{2}}$ and simplify.

Comment: This is a *show that* question. Using the intended result when answering the question is almost always disallowed in these questions.

Answer (score 0):

If $\frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac b{\cos A}$, that is a right angled triangle of one angle $A$, opposite side $a$, adjacent side $b$ and hypotenuse $\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}$.

Then $\sin A$ is really a scaled version of $a$ by $\dfrac 1{\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}}$, and $\cos A$ is a scaled version of $b$ by the same factor.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$\dfrac a{\sin A}=\dfrac b{\cos A}=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{\sin^2A+\cos^2A}}$$

Observe that the first two ratios have the same sign